# JavaFX : TextField always outputs "", so function gives NumberFormatException and others

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I wanted to do a test drive on JavaFx, and tried to create an app that can divide two values, but whenever i run it, it gives TextField output to be `""`.
Here's my code:

```
package com.example.javafxprojecttest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Divide extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("Divide values");
        Label divisionVal1 = new Label("Dividend : ");
        TextField dividend = new TextField();
        TextField divisor = new TextField();
        Label divisionVal2 = new Label("Divisor : ");
        Button divide = new Button("Divide");
        String dividendString = dividend.getText();
        String divisorString = divisor.getText();
        double d = Double.parseDouble(dividendString) / Double.parseDouble(divisorString);
        divide.setOnAction(e -> {
                    out.println(d);
                }
        );
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.addRow(0, divisionVal1, dividend);
        root.addRow(1, divisionVal2, divisor);
        root.addRow(2, divide);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:651)
    at com.example.javafxprojecttest/com.example.javafxprojecttest.Add.start(Add.java:24)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.example.javafxprojecttest.Add

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I dont know how to fix this nor do I know wht I have to add with this question for you to be able to answer it.
I tried to look at a lot of other questions here on StackOverflow but found none to be useful to me, and I am also rather new to StackOverflow(asking questions), so I dont know much on documenting the error.

Comment: You are trying to use the values of the fields before you even added them to the GUI. You can only do the calculation in the event callbacks, when the GUI is already up and running.

Comment: @RealSkeptic so what am i supposed to do, do it in main?

Comment: No, write event handlers for your fields.

Comment: @RealSkeptic like the one i did in my own answer that i posted just now?

Comment: That's exactly what @RealSkeptic told you to do.  Put the getText() calls in the EventHandler.

Answer (score 2):

Well i got it myself by just transferring all that to inside the button action.

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.setTitle("Divide values");
    Label divisionVal1 = new Label("Dividend : ");
    TextField dividend = new TextField();
    TextField divisor = new TextField();
    Label divisionVal2 = new Label("Divisor : ");
    Button divide = new Button("Divide");
    divide.setOnAction(e -> {
        String dividendString = dividend.getText();
        String divisorString = divisor.getText();
        double d = Double.parseDouble(dividendString) / Double.parseDouble(divisorString);
                out.println(d);
            }
    );
```